# Struggling with hierarchy of classes in c#

Tags: c#, class

I don't know if this is nested classes or not.

I'm writing a class in c# that should be called in the following way (for example):

```
test = main.Customers.List();
test = main.Customers.Add();
test = main.Orders.List();
test = main.Orders.Add();
```

So the whole point is have a hierarchy to split the methods into their correct group (Customers/Orders/etc).

I don't need the code inside the method but just how to accomplish the hierarchy.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  We have no idea what role `main` is or what type, nor what the other things are.  In my mind, for instance, `main.Customers.List()` makes no sense because `Customers` ought ***be*** a list, not expose one.  The code you are "struggeling" with would help.  Please read [ask] from the [help]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's like in vb.net.

BTW: I might been a little unclear about Customers. The point was to split the methods into categories. So Customers is not a list, but a category. main is the name of my top class.

So I can do for example main.Customers.GetUpdatedCustomers(fromdate)

Part of the code:

```
  private cCustomers myCustomer = new cCustomers();

  public cCustomers Customers 
  { 
     get
     {
        return myCustomer;
     }
  }

  public class cCustomers
```